# TypeScript return immutable/const/readonly Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutability, readonly

I want to have a function which returns an Array, but I want the returned Array to be readonly, so I should get a warning/error when I try to change its contents.

```
function getList(): readonly number[] {
   return [1,2,3];
}


const list = getList();
list[2] = 5; // This should result in a compile error, the returned list should never be changed
```

Can this be achieved in TypeScript?

Comment: There is one issue with using `Readonly<number[]>`. I can no longer use `for...of`, saying that type must have a method that returns an iterator.

Comment: ...and it [doesn't seem to work](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getList()%3A%20Readonly%3Cnumber%5B%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20return%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20list%20%3D%20getList()%3B%0D%0Alist%5B0%5D%20%3D%2042%3B). Surely I should be getting an error there?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate exactly. From what I can see, the accepted answer doesn't even work in the other question.

Comment: @series0ne: Yeah, see above. I went to try it so I could comment an example (I like to do that with dupes), and...it didn't work. :-)

Comment: In pure JS you may use `a => Object.freeze(a);` which turns the `a` array into shallow immutable. Attempting to change or delete it's items seems throw a "Type Error" in strict mode but fails silenty otherwise. If any one of the items is a reference type then it will remain mutable unless you freeze them i.e. recursively.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
function getList(): ReadonlyArray<number> {
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

const list = getList();

list[0] = 3; // Index signature in type 'ReadonlyArray<number>' only permits reading.
```

Try it in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getList()%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20list%20%3D%20getList()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alist%5B0%5D%20%3D%203%3B)

`ReadonlyArray<T>` is implemented like this:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    readonly [n: number]: T;
    // Rest of the interface removed for brevity.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I think `TypeScript` docs are lacking in this direction, didn't too many references to this functionality.

Answer (score 34):

The very code from OP now works since [TypeScript 3.4 introduced a new syntax for `ReadonlyArray`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#a-new-syntax-for-readonlyarray):

> While it's good practice to use `ReadonlyArray` over `Array` when no
>   mutation is intended, it's often been a pain given that arrays have a
>   nicer syntax. Specifically, `number[]` is a shorthand version of
>   `Array<number>`, just as `Date[]` is a shorthand for `Array<Date>`.
>
> TypeScript 3.4 introduces a new syntax for `ReadonlyArray` using a new
>   `readonly` modifier for array types.

This code now works as expected:

```
function getList(): readonly number[] {
   return [1,2,3];
}

const list = getList();
list[2] = 5; // <-- error
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDIwM5QBQCUAXIgE6oCGAJggDYCeiYIAtgEaqkDaAuogN4BYAFCIx5KCFJIuARgA0AJnkBmHgG4RAXxEiICXIlo4oiALwp0WXIU3DjuLor4WArOqA).

Answer (score 5):

The following will make the list readonly but the items in it not:

```
function getList(): Readonly<number[]> {
   return [1,2,3];
}

let list = getList();
list = 10; // error
list[1] = 5 // that is fine
```

And this one will make the list and the items of it readonly:

```
function getList(): ReadonlyArray<number> {
   return [1,2,3];
}

let list = getList();
list = 10; // error
list[1] = 5 // error as well
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript has a [`ReadonlyArray<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) type that does this:

> TypeScript comes with a ReadonlyArray type that is the same as Array with all mutating methods removed, so you can make sure you don’t change your arrays after creation

```
function getList(): ReadonlyArray<number> {
   return [1,2,3];
}

const list = getList();
list[2] = 5; // error

for (const n of list) {
    console.log(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.freeze` to return a readonly array without using any type annotations:

```js
function getList() {
  return Object.freeze([1,2,3]);
}

const list = getList();
list[2] = 5; // error

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is `as const` keyword.

"as const declares the content of a variable or constant as readonly and makes sure that the contents of the variable or constant are not changed"
[(src)](https://medium.com/lean-coders/understand-const-as-const-and-readonly-in-typescript-a-comprehensive-explanation-1b54f24b35d6#:%7E:text=const%20indicates%20that%20no%20new,or%20constant%20are%20not%20changed)

```
function getList() {
  return [1,2,3] as const
}

const list = getList();
list[2] = 5; // error
```

error: `Cannot assign to '2' because it is a read-only property.`

result what your ide will show:

```
function getList(): readonly [1, 2, 3]
```

**pro:** is it clean (no need to define return type manually or create new type)

**con:** not explicit