# How to throw an error at compile time for arguments without "as const"

Tags: typescript

I want to throw a compile time error when the argument that is provided was not "casted" `as const`. Is there any way to do this?
From what I understand, in my example the array is changed to a `readonly` array.
This is what I have so far:

```
function myFunc<T extends string[]>(arr: T): T {
    return arr;
}

const a = myFunc(["koo"] as const);
// Good, `a` is now `const a: ["koo"]`
// Should work


const b = myFunc(["koo"]); 
// Bad, `b` is now `string[]`
// Should throw, something like:
// TypeScript error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly string[]'
```

Comment: To what end? `as const` doesn't actually do anything at runtime, you have exactly the same JS either way, and a mutable array does meet all of the interface requirements of an immutable one (i.e. you'd only get an error if you passed an immutable array where a mutable one was required). Also your title directly contradicts your first sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the first sentence. And I've edited the code example to make more clear why its important to me to have this

Comment: It's still not clear why it's a problem to pass a `string[]` instead of a `readonly string[]`. They're compatible. If it's that `b` should also be `readonly`, the solution is not to infer the return type (which is not a good practice anyway, I'd enable [`typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/explicit-function-return-type/)): https://tsplay.dev/N9a6oN.

Comment: adding a return type (which is `T`) doesn't change the type of `a` or `b`. Think of `myFunc` as of  a library where i want to enforce the usage of a readonly, to give the user typesafty at a different stage of the application. It is a router lib where myFunc would define the routes and somewhere later the results can be used by a function that creates the <a href> and that function can be written with type support.

Comment: and you are right, there is not difference in my usecase for adding `readonly`, i've removed it

Comment: I don't know TypeScript enough, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003095/typescript-return-immutable-const-readonly-array may at least point towards a direction what you could try.

Comment: TypeScript’s `readonly` doesn’t really do very much so when you say it would “give the user type safety at a different stage of the application” I’m worried that this is an XY problem where requiring `as const` isn’t actually going to help.  But in any case, you can’t easily “require” a const assertion; why not just use a `const` type parameter in `myFunc`? Declared like `<const T extends string[]>`?

Comment: @jcalz perfect, that is what i was looking for, now the error doesnt really matter, as its typed to the string value[] and not to `string[]`, thanks! please submit your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to require that someone use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (`as const`) in a function call. You might be able to write some complicated thing that rejects `string[]`, but it would be fragile and have edge cases.

Instead, you should probably use a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) instead, which tells the compiler to treat function calls as if the user had used `as const`.  Like this:

```
function myFunc<const T extends string[]>(arr: T): T {
    return arr;
}

const a = myFunc(["koo"] as const);
// const a: ["koo"]

const b = myFunc(["koo"]); 
// const b: ["koo"]
```

Now both calls work as desired.  Of course nothing prevents someone from passing in some non-literal input:

```
const z = ["koo"];
// const z: string[]
const c = myFunc(z);
// const c: string[]
```

but you can't write `myFunc(z as const)` either, so a `const` type parameter is just as good as a `const` assertion for that purpose.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwQQZykQBVEBTADyjLABN9FCAnGMAcwG0BdAPgAoAhkyYAuEgEoxpAN4AoRAsRMyUEEyRCmAblkBfWbLxhCiAYgC8KDFj4cARAGs4cO11MMjhcToD0PxJ5EAmL2Ti5cBoGIAEYWVpiQto7Ort6yfgEERNEhyeGRWYgAXnGhKVy+-lFFYsysnBFREHFoCRB8RWkZTbVQLOzcQA)